# Why are these divs not lining up at the same height?

Tags: html, css

attempting to have three divs at the same height side by side. Having an issue where they are side by side by the height from the section above changes depending on the amount of text it contains. Tried following numerous guides online but they do not seem to solve my problem. If you could have a look at my code and the attached image and let me know where I am going wrong then that would be great! Cheers.

My code:

```css
html {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato";
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.category1title {
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.category1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #d3d3d3 0%, #57606f 75%);
}

.category1txt {
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.category2title {
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.category2 {
  width: 29%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 22px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 425px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #bd4f6c;
  background-image: linear-gradient(326deg, #d7816a 0%, #bd4f6c 74%);
}

.category2txt {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #181818;
}

#title {
  display: block;
  padding: 35px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#socialmedia {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#smtable {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}

#intro {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#about {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#two {
  width: 96%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="two">
  <table id="tabletwo">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="category2">
          <div class="category2title">
            Web Scraping:
          </div>
          <div class="category2txt">
            Our Devlopers have exstensive experience working with Python libraries like BeautifulSoup4 to scrape data from the web to create data streams.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="category2">
          <div class="category2title">
            Other:
          </div>
          <div class="category2txt">
            Can't find what you are looking for? Why not contact us via e-Mail or Twitter to see how we can help?
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="category2">
          <div class="category2title">
            Data:
          </div>
          <div class="category2txt">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Image of the problem below. The tops of the redish divs are at verying distances from the bottom of the grey div. Chrome's inspect shows no overlapping or any hint as to what is pushing the divs downwards.

[image: image of the issue]

Comment: vertical-align:top

Comment: https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/pogeWox